# The getTileUrl method is not automatically executed after arcgis js overrides the TiledMapServiceLayer

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I recently used arcgis js 3.17 to override the built-in TiledMapServiceLayer object on the project.The overloaded page loads the getTileUrl method to run locally, no problem.However, when I copy it to my colleague's computer, the page loads the JS file correctly, but the getTileUrl method does not run.There are no mistakes, no maps.Can anyone help solve this problem?

```
  constructor: function () {
        this.spatialReference = new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 });
        this.initialExtent = (this.fullExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent(-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0, this.spatialReference));

        this.tileInfo = new esri.layers.TileInfo({
            "rows": 256,
            "cols": 256,
            "compressionQuality": 0,
            "origin": {
                "x": -180,
                "y": 90
            },
            "spatialReference": {
                "wkid": 4326
            },
            "lods": [
              { "level": 2, "resolution": 0.3515625, "scale": 147748796.52937502 },
              { "level": 3, "resolution": 0.17578125, "scale": 73874398.264687508 },
              { "level": 4, "resolution": 0.087890625, "scale": 36937199.132343754 },
              { "level": 5, "resolution": 0.0439453125, "scale": 18468599.566171877 },
              { "level": 6, "resolution": 0.02197265625, "scale": 9234299.7830859385 },
              { "level": 7, "resolution": 0.010986328125, "scale": 4617149.8915429693 },
              { "level": 8, "resolution": 0.0054931640625, "scale": 2308574.9457714846 },
              { "level": 9, "resolution": 0.00274658203125, "scale": 1154287.4728857423 },
              { "level": 10, "resolution": 0.001373291015625, "scale": 577143.73644287116 },
              { "level": 11, "resolution": 0.0006866455078125, "scale": 288571.86822143558 },
              { "level": 12, "resolution": 0.00034332275390625, "scale": 144285.93411071779 },
              { "level": 13, "resolution": 0.000171661376953125, "scale": 72142.967055358895 },
              { "level": 14, "resolution": 8.58306884765625e-005, "scale": 36071.483527679447 },
              { "level": 15, "resolution": 4.291534423828125e-005, "scale": 18035.741763839724 },
              { "level": 16, "resolution": 2.1457672119140625e-005, "scale": 9017.8708819198619 },
              { "level": 17, "resolution": 1.0728836059570313e-005, "scale": 4508.9354409599309 },
              { "level": 18, "resolution": 5.3644180297851563e-006, "scale": 2254.4677204799655 }
            ]
        });

        this.loaded = true;
        debugger
        this.onLoad(this);
    },
    getTileUrl: function (level, row, col) {
        return "url//tile/" + level + "/" + row + "/" + col;         
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean you copy it to your colleagues computer?

Comment: I copied this JS file onto my colleague's computer

Comment: Just that file? What about all the dependencies?

Comment: Other dependent files are already on his computer, and only need to add this rewritten JS file

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but it's good.My problem is solved